# Will jQuery's remove() function cancel the request of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if jQuery's [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function will reliably cancel requests that have been triggered during page load. 
Given following setup:

```
<video>
  <source src="movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video>
  <source src="movie2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and they are quite big videos to return in the response (~40mb).

When I have this in my JS:

```
$(document).ready(isMobile);

function isMobile() {
  // condition that checks for mobile device here, next line executed if true
  $('video').remove(); 
};
```

will the video already requested still be loaded? Will any of the videos be loaded?

As you can assume this is about cancelling unnecessary loading of videos which wouldn't be displayed for mobile anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After running the following snippet, I noticed that it did indeed stop downloading the file after the current "chunk" finished downloading. This would prevent further loading by large sources.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('video').remove();
  }, 10000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4"  type="video/mp4" controls>
```

[image]

And after downloading/stopping 10 seconds in (The chunk finished downloading, and then stopped downloading more data):

[image]

Comment: thanks for confirming my observation. The reason I was asking is that apparently people on their mobile said the videos were still downloading. There seems some sort of discrepancy. But I'm not sure if that was their cache or if this behaves differently on mobile devices.

Comment: @supersize Worst case, just add the videos via jQuery if your mobile checks fail.

Comment: yeah I am aware of other solutions. I am just curious in general if the remove() api behaves differently on different browser (e.g. mobile)

Comment: @supersize - (without having checked the jquery source code) I highly doubt the `remove()` api has anything to do with stopping the download. It removes the element from the DOM — then it's up to the _browser implementation_ to notice and stop the download... so different browsers could behave differently; even chrome mobile vs. chrome desktop could be different.

Comment: @StephenP absolutely. I have tested it on Browserstack with different devices and frankly speaking they're all different. Not sure to accept this answer as it might lead to thinking it would always work. If you want you can provide an answer stating it is inconsistent, which you basically say in your comment.